# Deleted item remains in content database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, document-library, document

I deleted a document from a library in a document center site collection and also emptied the recycle bin.  I'm a farm administrator.  The document, however, still shows as a record in the `AllDocs` table in the content database.  How can I permanently remove it?

Comment: there are 2 recycle bin, did you deleted from both?

Comment: You're a champ.  put that up as an answer - I hadn't checked the "Deleted from end user recycle bin" portion of the site collection bin.

Comment: OK, i update the answer with the explanation,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two recycle bin in a Site collection, **1st level Recycle Bin** and **second-stage recycle bin**

If you delete the document, it goes to 1st stage recycle bin and if you delete it from their then it will go to 2nd stage recycle bin (still recoverable) but once you delete it from 2nd stage then its gone completely.

[Restore deleted items from the site collection recycle bin](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-deleted-items-from-the-site-collection-recycle-bin-5fa924ee-16d7-487b-9a0a-021b9062d14b#ID0EAAEAAA=2016)

Comment: in response to the answer I'll make a more explicit note that there are two "tabs" in the site collection recycle bin - one general one "End user Recycle Bin items" and "Deleted from end user Recycle Bin".  I did not perceive those two things at first so I think they may be easy for others to miss.